# This image has no active tags. Gitlab docker image registry

Tags: gitlab, docker-image, container-registry

I have a docker image in my Gitlab registry with 3 tags. Today I noticed that all my tags were deleted but **I can pull and push any tags to registry**, and on the site in docker registry tab I have a message:

> This image has no active tags
> The last tag related to this image was recently removed. This empty image and any associated data will be automatically removed as part of the regular Garbage Collection process. If you have any questions, contact your administrator.
> [image]

Expiration policy is disabled:
[image]

Where has gone my image's tags and why was it removed?

Comment: This seems to be a bug introduced recently https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/281150

Comment: looks similar, thanks!

Comment: hope it's will be fix soon)

Comment: It's already works!